# how to render a list of content-types in a block? (drupal 7)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Been reading/searching but can't seem to figure out how to do this without having to install a bunch of modules. I'm building a templete, and I'm trying to do the following:

```
region[content]
 - content-type[information-page]
  -- block[about-us]
   --- content-type[person]
   --- content-type[person]
   --- content-type[person]
   --- content-type[person]
```

I want to be able to generate many **content-type[person]** (each is an image, biography, etc) and append it to the **block[about-us]** that shows up only on **content-type[information-page]**. I'm looking for a simple solution, and don't quite understand too much about the preprocessing methods.

- First, is my structure all wrong? :\
- Should I make a **block--about-us.tpl.php**? How would I render **content-type[person]**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is with installing few modules: Views, CCK.

[Here](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode9) you have video explaining basics of views, and here about [CCK](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode7).

In short you need create new content type (seems that you have already done it). With Views module you have really flexible tool for choosing information you want display in your block. So your

```
-- block[about-us]
--- content-type[person]
--- content-type[person]
--- content-type[person]
--- content-type[person]
```

will be created automaticly by Views. With this you should manage without creating template.

For changing way how you display node content(as I understand `content-type[person]` part) you can use node templates system. [Here](http://drupal.org/node/17565) you have explanation how to do it.

Comment: Right, views is the best way of doing this. This allows you to be flexible about what to display, where and how. You need to get views, and Field API (ex-cck) already included in Drupal 7.

Comment: I ended up trying views out, and it solves the problem! thanks